# Java reading from text file and remove dash in string

Tags: java, file-io

I have a text file:

```
John Smith 2009-11-04
Jenny Doe 2009-12-29
Alice Jones 2009-01-03
Bob Candice 2009-01-04
Carol Heart 2009-01-07
Carlos Diaz 2009-01-10
Charlie Brown 2009-01-14
```

I'm trying to remove the dashes and store them as separate types: first, last, year,month,day and then add it to a sortedset/hashmap. But for some reason. It's not working right.

Here is my code:

```
public class Test {

    File file;
    private Scanner sc;
    //HashMap<Name, Date> hashmap = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * @param filename
     */
    public Test(String filename) {
        file = new File(filename);
    }

    public void openFile(String filename) {
        // open the file for scanning
        System.out.println("Test file " + filename + "\n");
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(new File("birthdays.dat"));
        } 
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Birthdays: Unable to open data file");
        }
    }

    public void readFile() {
        System.out.println("Name              Birthday");
        System.out.println("----              --------");
        System.out.println("----              --------");

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] split = line.split("[ ]?-[ ]?");

            String first = split[0];
            String last = split[1];
            //int year = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
            //int month = Integer.parseInt(split[3]);
            //int day = Integer.parseInt(split[4]);

                    Resource name = new Name(first, last);
                    System.out.println(first + " " + last + " " + split[2]  );
            //hashmap.add(name);

        }

    }

    public void closeFile() {
        sc.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
            ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner( new File(args[0]) );

                for( int i = 0; i < args.length; i++ ) {
                    //System.out.println( args[i] );

                    if( args.length == 0 ) {

                    }
                    else if( args.length >= 1 ) {

                    }
                //  System.out.printf( "Name %-20s Birthday", name.toString(), date.toString() );
                }

        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.err.println("Usage: Birthdays dataFile");
            // Terminate the program here somehow, or see below.
            System.exit(-1);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Birthdays: Unable to open data file");
            // Terminate the program here somehow, or see below.
            System.exit(-1);
        }   

        Test r = new Test(args[0]);
        r.openFile(args[0]);
        r.readFile();
        r.closeFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your regex for the splitting makes no sense, because the structure of the text file is different. Use this instead: `line.split("[ -]+")` (or just `line.split("[ -]")` without the `+` sign).

Answer (score 1):

Your splitting on dashes but your is program is build around a split using spaces.

Try just splitting on spaces

```
String[] split = line.split("\\s");
```

So `"John Smith 2009-11-04".split("[ ]?-[ ]?");` results in `["John Smith 2009", "11", "04"]` When what you want is for it to split on spaces `["John", "Smith", "2009-11-04"]`

Answer (score 1):

I would do this differently, first create a domain object:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private LocalDate date;

    //getters & setters

    //equals & hashCode

    //toString
}
```

Now create a method that parses a single `String` of the format you have to a `Person`:

```
//instance variable
private final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

public Person parsePerson(final String input) {        
    final String[] data = input.split("\\s+");
    final Person person = new Person();
    person.setFirstName(data[0]);
    person.setLastName(data[1]);
    person.setDate(LocalDate.parse(data[2], dateTimeFormatter));
    return person;
}
```

Note that the `DateTimeFormatter` is an instance variable, this is for speed. You should also set the `ZoneInfo` on the formatter if you need to parse dates not in your current locale.

Now, you can read your file into a `List<Person>` very easily:

```
public List<Person> readFromFile(final Path path) throws IOException {
    try (final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
        return lines
                .map(this::parsePerson)
                .collect(toList());
    }
}
```

And now that you have a `List<Person>`, you can sort or process them however you want.

You can even do this *while* creating the `List`:

```
public List<Person> readFromFile(final Path path) throws IOException {
    try (final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
        return lines
                .map(this::parsePerson)
                .sorted(comparing(Person::getLastName).thenComparing(Person::getFirstName))
                .collect(toList());
    }
}
```

Or have your `Person implements Comparable<Person>` and simply use natural order.

**TL;DR:** Use `Objects` for your objects and life becomes much simpler.

Comment: Could you explain more about 
public List<Person> readFromFile(final Path path) throws IOException {
    try (final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
        return lines
                .map(this::parsePerson)
                .sorted(comparing(Person::getLastName).thenComparing(Person::getFirstName))
                .collect(toList());
    }
}

Comment: @AlFord what do you mean by explain more?

Comment: I have this but it does not works:

private List<Person> name = new ArrayList<Person>();

public List<Person> readFromFile(final Path path) throws IOException {
      try (final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
     return lines
        .map(this::readFromFile)                                                    .sorted(comparing(Person::getLastName).thenComparing(Person::getFirstName))
                 .collect(toList());
     }
 }

 private Object toList() {
  return null;
 }

Comment: @AlFord can you read that block of code you just added to the comments? I certainly can't. Also "does not work" is utterly unhelpful is diagnosing the problem. Post a new question if you wish.

Comment: @AlFord what is `private Object toList() { return null; } `?? This should be an `import static` from [`Collectors.toList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--)!

Comment: It seems like the reason why I can't use .map and .filter is because Eclipse does not recognize Java8 lamda expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex:

```
private static Pattern LINE_PATTERN
        = Pattern.compile("(.+) (.+) ([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})");

...

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        Matcher matcher = LINE_PATTERN.matcher(line);
        if (!matcher.matches()) {
            // malformed line
        } else {
            String first = matcher.group(1);
            String last = matcher.group(2);
            int year = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
            int month = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(4));
            int day = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(5));
            // do something with it
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting on spaces and a hyphen.  This pattern does not exist.

```
    String[] split = line.split("[ ]?");

    String first = split[0];
    String last = split[1];

    line = split[2];
    //now split the date 
    String[] splitz = line.split("-");
```

or something like this might work:

```
     String delims = "[ -]+";
     String[] tokens = line.split(delims);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question right then Here is answer. Check it out.

```
  List<String> listGet = new ArrayList<String>();
    String getVal = "John Smith 2009-11-04";
    String[] splited = getVal.split("[\\-:\\s]");
    for(int j=0;j<splited.length;j++)
    {
        listGet.add(splited[j]);

    }
    System.out.println("first name :"+listGet.get(0));
    System.out.println("Last name :"+listGet.get(1));
    System.out.println("year is :"+listGet.get(2));
    System.out.println("month is :"+listGet.get(3));
    System.out.println("day is :"+listGet.get(4));
```

OP :

```
first name :John
Last name :Smith
year is :2009
month is :11
day is :04
```

Comment: I tried this with a text file but it repeatedly loop through John Smith. Then, it gives error saying no line found.

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877483/how-to-read-data-from-a-text-file-and-save-some-data-from-it-to-an-array